# Symfony - Create Service object with parameters

Tags: api, symfony, service, dependencies, inject

I created a new service in my symfony application:

```
namespace AppBundle\Service;

class CustomService {

    public function __construct($username, $password) {
        // stuff
    }

    public function getItems() {

    }

}
```

and configured in config.yml:

```
services:
    custom_service:
        class:          AppBundle\Service\CustomService
```

My question is, how to create an object from this service with multiple arguments?

Like:

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class CustomController extends Controller {

    public function listAction() {

        $custom_service = $this->get('custom_service'); //how to pass multiple arguments here?

        // Next i would use my custom service, like:
        $items = $custom_service->getItems();

    }

}
```

Anybody knows how to solve this issue?

Thanks and Greetings!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you don't.  The container supports injecting dependencies.  Doing what you propose kind of defeats the purpose of using a dependency injection container.

One work around is to add an init method to your object.

```
$custom_service = $this->get('custom_service')->init($additional_arguments);
```